# Armature rotates in blender upon exporting as fbx [Still not working]

Tags: armature

Upon exporting my character in blender as fbx it rotates by -90.

The question linked has not fixed my problem. :|

I have already applied transform, rotation, and scale.
This happens in blender right after i export and it brings me back to the 3D view.

The character used to export normally, until i recently rechecked some animations and edited the bones.
[image]

[image]

Comment: @Felix FBX uses a different coordinate system, set the y-up option when importing as shown in the link posted by SixthOfFour.

Comment: so you're exporting it , then importing it again? Or is it happening as soon as you export? Make sure to apply Scale , location and rotation ( CTRL + A ) .

Comment: Exporting it, and it happens as soon as i export. Already tried apply rotation and location...

Comment: If this is still relevant, this would need a bug report on [our tracker](https://developer.blender.org/maniphest/task/create/?project=2&type=Bug)…